# How to merge three videos on one screen with ffmpeg

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I want to merge 3 videos using `ffmpeg`.  My new video should be similar to this:
[image]

Videos have no sound at all.

My video resolution is `560x448` with frame rate 25fps.

My script is:

```
ffmpeg -i C_L_560x448_40_static_maxSSIM_QP23_B2.avi -i maxSSIM_realTime_C_L_560x448.avi -i C_L_560x448_40_static_maxSSIM_QP31_B4.avi -filter_complex "[0:v][1:v][2:v]hstack; format=yuv420p[v];" -map "[v]" -map "[a]" -ac 2 output.avi
```

but I get `[AVFilterGraph @ 00000000007335c0] Too many inputs specified for the "hstack" filter. Error initializing complex filters. Invalid argument`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify inputs for these multi-input filters if the number is different than the default value, typically 2.

```
-filter_complex "[0:v][1:v][2:v]hstack=3,format=yuv420p[v]"
```

(I see no filter output labelled `[a]`. I assume you've omitted that)

Comment: I updated my code to `ffmpeg -i C_L_560x448_40_static_maxSSIM_QP23_B2.avi -i maxSSIM_realTime_C_L_560x448.avi -i C_L_560x448_40_static_maxSSIM_QP31_B4.avi -filter_complex "[0:v][1:v][2:v]hstack=3,format=yuv420p[v];" -map "[v]" output.avi` and I get error `No such filter: ' '`

Comment: I suppose `[a]` is for audio, right? I have no audio.

Comment: There shouldn't be any semi-colon at the end of the filters.